# pl/sql find greatest common factor from a table

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to find the greatest common factor for some numbers that i have put into a table. So far I have the function that is suppose to calculate the gcf

```
CREATE FUNCTION gcd (x INTEGER, y INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER AS
   ans INTEGER;
BEGIN
   IF (y <= x) AND (x MOD y = 0) THEN
      ans := y;
   ELSIF x < y THEN 
      ans := gcd(y, x);
   ELSE
      ans := gcd(y, x MOD y);
   END IF;
   RETURN ans;
END;
```

and here I create and random populate my table

```
DROP TABLE numere
/
CREATE TABLE numbers (number NUMBER(3) NOT NULL)
/
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
number NUMBER(3);
cursor c1 is
   SELECT * FROM note;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
      number:=dbms_random.value(20,100);
      insert into numbers values(number);
   end loop;
   commit;
END;
/
```

How can I integrate the gcf into my code? I want to display the numbers followed by their gcf.

Comment: where is your code? Where do you want to display the numbers?

Comment: i want to display the numbers on the screen using dbms_output.put_line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your gcd function. It seems to me not working. There are many on the web. This is one of them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_gcd (
      p_n1    IN  POSITIVE
  ,   p_n2    IN  POSITIVE
  )
  RETURN POSITIVE
  IS
      l_n1    POSITIVE := p_n1;
      l_n2    POSITIVE := p_n2;
  BEGIN
      WHILE NOT (l_n1 = l_n2)
      LOOP
          CASE SIGN(l_n1 - l_n2)
          WHEN +1
          THEN l_n1 := l_n1 - l_n2;
          ELSE l_n2 := l_n2 - l_n1;
          END CASE;
      END LOOP;
      RETURN (l_n1);
  END find_gcd;
  /
```

You can simply amend your PL/SQL block to call the gcd function and print out the results (I here assumed you want to find the gcd for each number and the following number in your table, so I used [LEAD](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lead.php) function):

```
DECLARE
lv_number NUMBER(3);
lv_gcd INTEGER;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
      lv_number:=dbms_random.value(20,100);
      insert into numbers values(lv_number);
   end loop;
   commit;

   FOR i in (select COL_VAL, lead(COL_VAL) over (order by rowid) nxt_val from numbers)
   LOOP
   lv_gcd := find_gcd(i.COL_VAL, i.nxt_val);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('GCD for '||TO_CHAR(i.COL_VAL)||' and '|| TO_CHAR(i.nxt_val) ||' is '||TO_CHAR(lv_gcd));
   END LOOP;

END;
```

/